# Google Cloud Platform: Physical snapshot storage location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) says:

> Compute Engine stores multiple copies of each snapshot redundantly across multiple locations with automatic checksums to ensure the integrity of your data.

I'm wondering about the *multiple locations* part and can't seem to find a definite answer. What exactly does that mean? When I do a snapshot of a disk in `us-east1`, is the physical data distributed to other geographic locations, and if yes, where to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots are a global resource, as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources#globalresources):

> Global resources are accessible by any resource in any zone within the same project. When you create a global resource, you do not need to provide a scope specification

This means that Google manages the storage and redundancy of the resource across global resources without exposing the details to the customer.

Comment: Ok, they don't need to be scoped. But the question still remains where the parts of the snapshots are physically stored. I cannot imagine that Google syncs every snapshot to every location around the globe, that would be a huge waste of resources, especially since snapshots are seldom read. From a compliance and GDPR point of view it is essential to know where snapshot data really ends up, physically. In our case it must not leave the EU, for example.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that. Yes, I would assume that not everything would be replicated across every location, but global resources are meant to be multi-regional at the very least. This may be a conversation you need to have with a Google representative. However, GCP do claim to be GDPR compliant (https://cloud.google.com/security/gdpr/):

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are multi-regional when you don't specify a particular location, for example `eu` means it's spread across the EU zones.
Please check this link for more

Comment: Which link should get checked?